# count Down Timer data of notification push (FCM) when the app is closed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good morning, I am looking for a suggestion / idea for a topic that is giving me headaches. It turns out that I am sending *FCM* push notifications from my server in Node, all fine with that, but the problem is that this notification is a new request for the app's dispatcher and he only has 30 seconds to accept it, otherwise it will be rejected. In the foreground and background I have no problem, but when the application is closed and when the user clicks on the notification, only at that time the 30 seconds are discounted, I would like it to be discounted in some way while the application is closed and when you click on the notification or open the app, you will see how many seconds are left and they haven't just started. Thanks for reading and I await your suggestions.

Comment: To make it work you will need to send the notification data in "data" key only that way you can handle this issue.

Comment: Yes, I send only "data" without "notification", just add a custom notification in _onMessageReceived_. The problem is when the application is closed, the notification arrives and the data also when it is opened or clicked on the notification, but it does not deduct the 30 seconds that it has to accept the order. It starts with 30, it does not discount when it is closed, for obvious reasons, so I would not know what to do.

Comment: When your app is not running there is no code that will count the time. You should start your app via intent when the FCM data message is received